Adjusting size of legend items without overlap in layout view of ArcGIS Pro
I am trying to increase the text size of my legend so it's easier to read but I am running into issues with the heatmap scale.

The "Dense" and "Sparse" labels start to overlap when I increase the font size.
Is there any way that I can increase the font size without this overlap occurring?

When you open the overall legend properties, click on the specific legend item (in this case the heatmap layer) in your table of contents. From there your legend options will change to a specifically adjust the selected heat map element. Under 'Sizing' you can increase the Patch height, which will lengthen the gradient strip symbol, which you can increase to your liking until it fits both labels at your desired text size!
Hope this helps.
